# Tomcat - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: apache, tomcat

I downloaded Tomcat 6 from [Tomcat Website](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) and try to install. I found the .exe file in C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin but when i run the exe file the command prompt disappeared after show "The system cannot find the file specified". I already installed JDK 6 update 29 in my system. Please advice

Comment: what version did you download; the one with or without the service wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to "guess" I would say that the JAVA_HOME is not set. But to confirm :
Can you go the command line, make sure that JAVA_HOME is set correctly, startup tomcat (from command line) ? If you run into errors, please send the text output.

Answer (score 2):

I had a simmilar problem after installing a java update, but JAVA_HOME was set correctly. If you run tomcat as a service, you might have to right click on the tomcat icon and open java tab and change java virtual machine path or just set "use default".

Answer (score 1):

Try to run "startup.bat" to start a tomcat instance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `your/path/tomcat` and execute script `catalina_start.bat` .I had the same issue and this worked for me (though I installed Tomcat as a part of XAMPP package)